# 13 year old adopted shelter cat will not eat any kind of meat

Tags: cats, feeding

I adopted a 12 y/o (now 13) cat from a shelter. Although the shelter said she had always been in a shelter she was not socialized when I adopted her. She was eating Science Diet senior kibble and I have been feeding her that since her adoption.  She will not eat any kind of wet cat food or even human meats (tuna, salmon or shrimp).  She will lick the sauce off SOME canned food but will not even touch 'sauce only or stew' types of food.  She will eat greenies & temptations treats.  She drinks almost an entire bowl full of water every day.

She's been with me almost a year and most times won't run and hide as long as I don't come directly at her.  I can only touch her occasionally. She will come to me sometimes to be brushed but that lasts less than a minute or two. On rare occasions she will allow me to stroke her once or twice. I can't hold her or pick her up. She has the freedom of my townhouse and runs up and down the stairs, sometimes just for fun. She LOVES to play! Jumps and leaps and runs while playing & yells at me when I need to stop. BUT, I can tell she's lost weight and I don't know how to get her to eat something that will give her moisture in her food AND put some weight on her.

The water is important as the shelter told me when I adopted her that she has the early stages of kidney disease.  My feline only Vet just retired (not that I could get my cat to her) and I'm trying to find a 'mobile vet' to check her out. There aren't many, none that specialize in cats and none of the are willing to come since she cannot be held.

I already love her dearly and I'm worried. I've always taken my previous cats for bi-yearly checkups but I can't with her.  Anyone with ideas?  (fyi - pate and blending food into mush doesn't make a difference.  Thanks!

Comment: I do not k ow cats well, but to add water to the kibbles?

Comment: Just to check, what *brands* of food have you tried? Have you used premium "real meat" foods, or the basic "chunks and gravy" variety that tends to use textured vegetable protein?

Answer (score 2):

My own cat is 15, in good health though her kidneys are starting to have a bit of trouble, and still prefers dry kibble for regular meals, though she likes the "gravy" wet foods as a treat. Yes, my vet would prefer she get more of her moisture in food, and encourages me to keep trying, but in the end the cat likes what she likes and I can't argue with that.

I got her a recirculating water bowl -- had to try several; she decided a ceramic fountain with filter, placed in the living room rather than kitchen, was acceptable -- and hearing the water noise does seem to encourage her to drink more.

You do what you can. Don't stress too much about it.